# 70's or 80's movie with motorcycle equipped with computer display and rifle holster

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

I watched this movie around end of the 80s. One of the main characters (male) was driving some racing motorcycle which had like computer display board giving various information and feedback. I remember the biker had some guns and could perform various shooting acrobatics while driving the bike. The setting of the movie was like in Mad Max (post-apocalyptic), as I remember a lot of endless desert ambient. There are 2 attractive women dressed with spandex (despite the hot weather), one blonde, one brunette. It could as well be a movie from the 70s (for sure, a B-production), but unfortunately I cannot remember the story line. Almost forgot that there are few soft core scenes here and there. I got this flashback couple of months ago and it's torturing me ever since. Thanks

Comment: Having seen so many interesting suggestions so far, I definitely can say that the computer display in the bike of the unknown movie was not that "advanced" as the one in the movie Warrior of the Lost World. I apologize to everyone for the incorrect use of comments and replies to commenters I've done so far -it's my first time in a forum like this one. I'll take a detailed look especially at the formatting

Comment: now this is driving me nuts too >_< I thought it was Warrior of the Lost World at first, but there's no spandex blonde brunettes, two gun acrobatics, and not a lot of endless desert ambiance.  Going to look for it more tonight. THERE IS HOWEVER a few "erotic" scenes, best example is in the bar where interpretive somewhat BSDM erotic dance takes place by leather-spandex clad actors.

Comment: @NOP The erotic scene I remember from this unknown movie was indeed a sexual intercourse between the brunette and her mate. Nothing too explicit, though. Both were part of the bad guys gang, if my memory serves me right...

Comment: ^_^ We wound up with a lot of incorrect answers, but not necessarily wrong ones, which will help the next person searching for a film about a motorcycle with a computer interface.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally found out the name of the movie: [The final executioner](https://youtu.be/tCvGM5wJVFg). I strongly appreciate your suggestions, folks. I apologize for some confusing hints I provided, as it’s been more than 20-25 years ago since I watched it for the first time. Few details to highlight:

1. The movie is in fact Italian (*L’ultimo guerriero*).
2. The setting is a desert after a nuclear holocaust.
3. The main character is not the one who rides the motorbike. Instead, the biker is the highest ranked bad guy in the film after the big boss (a female character). Besides the black leather suit, the bike and the rifle, the guy has a samurai sword and wears a black mask as a helmet.
4. The bike computer was not as sophisticated as I remembered (sorry for this). However, the bad guy’s bike has a screen that allows him to trigger a shotgun (or a certain weapon) installed on the bike.
5. There were no acrobatic shots while driving bikes (sorry for this too).
6. The story line is about a guy who seeks revenge for his girlfriend’s rape and murder.

Comment: Thank you, this was killing me! I've seen so many of these post apocalypse movies, but never heard of this one. Most of them were made by the Italians.

Comment: Amazing how many similar movies there are.

Comment: I was going to say, completely not surprised it's Italian.  Thanks for continuing the hunt to the end!  I kept coming up with the answers we all attempted in searches.  Don't worry about the incorrect descriptions, everything was probably perceived as VERY high-fantasy back then.

Comment: I'm glad you found your answer. It was bugging me, too.

Answer (score 8):

Could it be [Deathsport (1978)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077414/?ref_=ttls_li_tt)? It fits the time-frame, David Carradine battles on and off the motorcycle. There are a couple women in it and some soft core scenes. Makes sense it didn't fit. I don't remember the motorcycles a GUI or displaying any info.

Comment: Can you add more details about how this matches the question?

Comment: It's not Deathsport, although it looked pretty alike in terms of scenery and motorbikes. The main character (who owns the bike) was a black-haired man with some beard (or goatee, not completely sure) and wore a black leather suit. Unlike Deathsport, the weapons are conventional ones, not laser beams

Comment: Considering the "intelligent" motorcycle the only other thing that rings a bell, although I haven't seen it, is [Warrior of the Lost World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warrior_of_the_Lost_World).

Comment: The full movie of that one is at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yEGkmBJR1W8 if anyone wants to check it out.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Warrior of the Lost World is the best shot so far, but it's not the movie I'm looking for. However, the motorcycle model looks pretty alike, but without the cannons. I do remember, though, that the guy in the unknown movie had a rifle

Answer (score 8):

I'm thinking "[Megaforce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megaforce)" is the answer.  Not really post-apocalyptic but most of it took place in the desert. Barry Bostwick was indeed sporting facial hair for this one. Unfortunately he was wearing the Spandex.

[image]

It's pretty dreadful BTW.

Comment: Jinx! ^_^ That said, in his comment to the other guy, he said no lasers, and the protagonist had black hair.

Comment: Did Megaforce have lasers?

Comment: The trailer does. :)

Comment: Oh lord, I thought it was more present day tech.  I had also forgotten the Estes Model Rocket launchers lol  No lasers in this trailer though: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZERYyFxc0lg  And Persis may be sporting Spandex as well.

Comment: Gotta love that 70s color scheme: Brown, other brown, slightly darker brown, slightly lighter brown that might be considered tan or beige.

Answer (score 8):

Is it possible that you're thinking of the 1982 *[Megaforce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megaforce)*?

> The story involves two fictional countries, the peaceful Republic of Sardun and their aggressive neighbor Gamibia. Unable to defend themselves from a Gamibian incursion, Sardun sends Major Zara (Persis Khambatta) and General Byrne-White (Edward Mulhare) to ask the help of MegaForce – a secret army composed of international soldiers from throughout the western world, equipped with advanced weapons and vehicles. The MegaForce leader, Commander Ace Hunter (Barry Bostwick), will lead a mission to destroy the Gamibian forces, which are ironically led by his rival, and former military academy friend, Duke Gurerra (Henry Silva).
>
> While Hunter composes an elaborate battle plan to destroy Gurerra's forces, Zara tries out to become a member of MegaForce. As she executes the various tests, Hunter's feelings of affection toward her grow. And while she passes the tests, he is unable to allow her to participate in their raid, because her presence, as an outsider, would disrupt the trust and familiarity of his force.
>
> Eventually, MegaForce successfully para-drops its attack vehicles into Gamibia and Hunter mounts his sneak attack against Gurerra's forces. Although they manage to destroy his base, Gurerra has set a trap for them at the team's only means of escape – a dry lake bed where the cargo planes will pick them up. Gurerra sends his tanks to secure the lake bed while Hunter comes up with a plan to attack Gurerra from behind by crossing over a mountain range the enemy tanks had turned their backs toward.
>
> The plan succeeds, and MegaForce manages to break through Gurerra's tanks, but one of MegaForce's cargo planes is damaged in the process. Having to abandon their high-tech vehicles (which they program to self-destruct), the team successfully makes it on foot to the last plane, except for Hunter. The commander, instead, makes his own dramatic escape on his motorcycle after it deploys airfoils and a rocket motor and catches up with the cargo plane in midair. Although he has lost the battle, Gurerra shows admiration for Hunter's cunning, and he gives his old friend a thumbs up.

It's got high-tech motorcycles, skintight bodysuits (albeit on the men too), and sports a lot of guns and stunt riding.

Comment: I don't remember having seen tanks in the movie :(  Anyway, I appreciate your suggestion

Answer (score 8):

It could also be *Warrior of the Lost World*, which is best watched as an MST3K episode.  The hero with the bike is played by that guy from *The Paper Chase*.

> The Rider arrives on his advanced motorcycle with its artificial intelligence computer Einstein. He crashes but manages to pass through the "wall of illusion" and is found and brought back to health by the Enlightened Elders. They have chosen him to lead their fight against the evil Omega, an Orwellian state run by the evil Prossor. The Elders are allied with the resistance movement, the Outsiders. The Rider first helps Nastasia and the other Outsiders by rescuing McWayne, Nastasia's father and leader of the Outsiders. While the Rider and McWayne successfully escape, Nastasia is captured and subjected to brainwashing by Prossor.

It's one of many crappy movies featuring Donald Pleasance, who seems to be rebelling against the terrible direction and trying to turn in a competent performance.

Comment: *Warrior of the Lost World* is the best shot so far, but it's not the movie I'm looking for. However, the motorcycle model looks pretty alike, but without the cannons. The computer is not as sophisticated either and the main character has a rifle

Answer (score 7):

What about [Battletruck?](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battletruck) It has been many years since I saw it but the hero had a super motorcycle in a post-apocalyptic world.  The early 1980s release date works too.

[Battletruck--Full Movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0fl9FqTlvA)

Comment: I don't remember a massive armored truck like the one in _Battletruck_. In the unknown movie, the bike used by the main character is not the motocross kind either, but rather the one shown in [Warrior of the Lost World](https://youtu.be/5euYoAy4DL4)

Comment: Perhaps you should focus on the bike. Props are often recycled between productions to save money. I cannot count the times I have seen the "Starship Trooper" body armor on TV or in low budget movies.  That said, do some research on the production and the bike itself, assuming it is the exact one you remember.

Answer (score 3):

Timerider: The Adventure of Lyle Swann.

It has a motorbike, helmet mounted HUD, beautiful girl and some guns. I am not sure if they were in holster which itself is required to be mounted on aforementioned two wheeled vehicle.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timerider:_The_Adventure_of_Lyle_Swann)

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJGm76S-0xw)

[Whole film in a language of fine cuisine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUZP5BYIVFk)

Comment: The main character in _Timerider_ wears a red suit, so there's no match there. Besides, the motorcycle in the unknown movie is more like the one in [Warrior of the Lost World](https://youtu.be/5euYoAy4DL4)