# 80s (could be early 90s) post-apocalyptic road warrior like movie

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

The movie started in a desert, with a man in agony who's missing his legs (probably ripped by stretching with bikes or cars). A man (the protagonist) comes along and gives him water. They have a little chat, probably asking to be killed, and I'm not sure but I think he does shoot him. I think next scene the protagonist is being chased (Mad Max style) and he is riding a black modified motorcycle that even delivers grenades near the exhaust from a push of a button in the handle.

Comment: Please go to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and walk through the prompts there. See if you can answer any of those questions to help you elicit further details.

Comment: Also, check out the answers to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178261/70s-or-80s-movie-with-motorcycle-equipped-with-computer-display-and-rifle-hols. I feel like there could be some overlap.

Answer (score 4):

The movie is [*Steel Frontier* (1995)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114537) starring Joe Lara and Brion James.

> Mad Max meets the Man With No Name in this futuristic story of a gunfighter (Joe Lara), who goes after a band of marauders who are terrorizing everyone and killing indiscriminately. As with the spaghetti westerns, the lone gunman enters into a town where the people have lost the will to fight back and proceeds to kill off the bad guys single-handedly. But once he is out-numbered totally and wounded, some do find the capability to fight back. Chief of those who try to aid him is a widow (Stacie Foster) with a young son. Brion James plays the general in charge of the marauders.

Trailer:

Comment: I've edited in some basic info about this, could you add in how this matches the OPs description?

Comment: You also may want to [register your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/345161).

Comment: WOW! You Nailed It!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

This could be *Warriors of the Wasteland* (1983), a movie with people riding around in the badlands on bikes and in bizarrely modified cars.  Watching it, it is painfully obvious that it is aping *The Road Warrior*.

At about 14:00, the hero (played by Giancarlo Prete) strikes up a conversation with a critically injured man, who he eventually agrees to mercy kill.

(The film also features Fred Williamson, who also played a tough guy in another 1983 post-apocalyptic motorcycling motion picture, *Warrior of the Lost World*.)

Comment: Negative, not the movie I'm looking for, but thanks for your reply.To add a little detail, the protagonist I believe is wearing black leather, or has a black leather coat. The motorcycle is not slim, its covered in various mods and is black as well.