B-movie circa mid-80s about a guy with a motorcycle, possibly post apocalyptic
Saw this, or part of it, when I was a kid. I mostly remember the guy riding his motorcycle/dirtbike across vast expanses of barren land in a dreary, possibly foggy landscape. It's possibly set in the future as I think the bike had modded silver-metallic bodywork to make it look futuristic.
I think there's only one other character, a woman, probably younger than the man. I don't think they start out together, but find each other in the course of the film.

People might mine various answers from https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178261/70s-or-80s-movie-with-motorcycle-equipped-with-computer-display-and-rifle-hols

Feels like I've seen dozens of movies matching this exact description, can you narrow it down a bit more? They were mass-produced in Italy in the 80ies. An abandoned quarry, a bunch of motorcycles, and one or two washed out American actors and you have yourself a movie.

It could be Deathsport (1978), starring David Carradine and Claudia Jennings, who had a 13 year age gap.
It's definitely post-apocalyptic, and a lot of it involves travel across barren wastelands on a futuristic motorbike.
Does this look familiar?


Thirteen years is nothing in the movies!

This sounds like Timerider: The Adventure of Lyle Swann from 1982.  It stars Fred Ward as a cross country dirt bike racer from the 1980s who is mistakenly sent back in time to November 5, 1877.
Plot details from Wikipedia:

Lyle Swann is a well-known dirt bike motorcycle racer who is in the
desert competing in the Baja 1000, a multiclass vehicle cross-country
race. Swann has a reputation for being a great rider but is plagued by
technical problems from the high-tech gadgetry he incorporates into
his C and J framed XT500 Yamaha. When Swann accidentally goes far off
course, he stumbles across a time travel experiment that utilizes
"maser velocity acceleration" to send objects (in this case, a simian
subject by the name of Esther G.) back in time.
Swann rides through the field and gets sent back to November 5, 1877.
The scientists in charge of the experiment soon realize what has
happened, but Swann rides off, unaware of what has happened to him,
before he can be returned to the present. While taking a swim break in
a local pond, he runs into a gang of outlaws led by Porter Reese, who
becomes obsessed with stealing Swann's motorcycle, and the outlaws
pursue Swann into the small village of San Marcos, but his red suit
and dirtbike scare the local Mexicans, who think he is 'El Diablo'
(Spanish for 'The Devil').
There, he meets a beautiful woman, Claire Cygne, who gives him a safe
place to hide ...


Another possibility to add to the list is MEGAFORCE from 1982. The protagonist is in charge of a team that utilizes all sorts of futuristic vehicles, but the film is mostly known for the motorcycle scenes:

It does indeed take place in a war-torn, possibly post-apocalyptic desert. And there is indeed a woman who ends up riding around with the bearded protagonist, Ace Hunter. The age difference wasn't that pronounced, but may have appeared so because of his beard and wildly magnificent hair.
The motorcycles are mostly white with gold & black accents (see image above).
